# Find the General PDE that would give the following weak formulation.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ a regular bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $B$ a regular subset of $\Omega$ such that $\bar{B} \subset \Omega$ (think of $B$ as ball inside $\Omega$).

Denote $X =\{ u \in (L^2(\Omega))^3 \ | \ div \ u =  0 \text{ in } \Omega\ \text{ with } \int_\Omega u \ \mathrm{d}x= 0 \}$.

We then pose $U = \{ u|_{\Omega \setminus B} \ | \ u \in X \}$ which I know is a closed subset of the Hilbert space $(L^2(\Omega \setminus B))^3$, and therefore a good candidate for Lax-Milgram theorem.

Now, let $G \in U$ solution of the following weak formulation :

$$\int_{\Omega \setminus B} G \cdot \varphi = - \int_{\Omega \setminus B} \xi \cdot \varphi, \quad \forall \varphi \in X$$
where $\xi$ is a fixed vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$. *(The existence and uniqueness of $G$ is given
by Lax-Milgram theorem applied in $U$)*

**My question is the following :** I would like to know if there is a somehow natural strong formulation of this PDE written in weak forms. I tried writing something, but I'm having troubles dealing with the boundary condition (on $\Omega$ and on the inclusion $B$).
For sure I know that I will have the divergence free condition $div \ G = 0$.

Any ideas or advices are welcomed.